# How to achieve the desired output

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Below are the 3 tables from which I have using the data

QuotationMaster

```
QuoteID QuoteNo  CustomerName TotalSellQty
------------------------------------------
1       Q1        Name1          60  
2       Q2        Name2          30
3       Q3        Name3          10
4       Q4        Name4          50
5       Q5        Name5          40
```

QuoteItemDetails : one quote can have many items

```
QuoteItemID  QuoteID    ItemDescription    ItemID   
-----------------------------------------------
   1          1         AAA                1 
   1          1         BBB                2       
   2          2         BBB                2 

  QuoteBatchDetails : one QuoteItem can have many batches of QuoteID and ItemID are the common columns. BatchNo is varchar

QuotebatchID  QuoteID   BatchNo    ItemID  BatchQty  Date
--------------------------------------------------------
   1          1          A          1         20    1/2/2013
   2          1          B          1         30    2/2/2013
   3          1          C          1         10    3/3/2013
   4          2          E          2         10    4/3/2013
   5          2          F          2         20    5/3/2013
```

I want to display the below result in **CRYSTAL REPORT** based on QuoteID as parameter.For each Item Displayed we will also display the BatchNo,Date and BatchQty where Sum(BatchQty) is the TotalQty.

*** But in the front end I will not be displaying the BatchNo Date and BatcchQty (only the values).

```
     QuoteItemID  QuoteID    ItemDescription  TotalQty       
              --------------------------------------------------
  First Row       1          1             AAA          60

                  BatchNo    Date                      BatchQty
                   A         1/2/2013                    20
                   B         2/2/2013                    30
                   C         3/3/2013                    10


  Second Row      2          2             BBB           30 

                  BatchNo    Date                      BatchQty
                   E         4/3/2013                    10
                   F         5/3/2013                    20
```

How Can I achieve the above result.

[image]

Comment: can you let me know how to pass parameter to subreport

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into just using sub reports in Crystal Reports? This should get you the above results. You could pass your QuoteId to the QuoteItemDetails sub report to only show QuoteItemDetails base on that QuoteId and then you could pass the ItemId to a QuoteBatchDetails sub report from the QuoteItemDetails sub report and display the appropriate data.

Here is a link on how to create sub reports http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/d05ad954-f8a2-2e10-db9f-bb0f13a7cb1c?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&51887500358899.

Hope this gives you some insight.

Comment: Hi, I am completely new to subreports.Anywaz I have an idea can you let me know if this is possible.As you can see the desired output..I am thinking to get all the item Details depending on QuoteID using a SP.OK.Now when it comes to subreport,I will create another SP which takes QuoteID as parameter and get all the BatchDetails.So in order to link between these two Reports, Is it possible to link through the ITEMID in the main SP so that the related data is loaded into the subreport.

Comment: Yes ... you can easily link fields between the sub reports ... there is actually a wizard for it when you create the sub report.

Comment: I am trying to do the same.Will let you know if I am successfull.

Comment: Hi. I have created another SP                                 Create proc [dbo].[SD_GetBatchReportDetails] @QuoteID INT as Begin select BatchNo,ExpiryDate,BatchSellQty,QuoteID,ItemID from view_SD_GetBatchReportDetails where QuoteID=@QuoteID End. Now I created a subreport which takes QuoteID as parameter.Now I linked the two reports using ItemID. But for an Item if there are 2 BatchNo's that Item is shown twice in the crystal report.I will update the image in the question.

Comment: The subreport is now showing below the main Row.But extending beyond the main row for all the Items.

Comment: You might need to configure your detail sections to prevent all the overlapping.

Comment: All fine now.As I told you I have created another SP with QuoteID as parameter which I am using for SubReport.How to pass parameter to the Subreport.

Comment: My subreport name is Sub.So i have used the below code.but no luck                 objReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@QuoteBatchID", ValQuoteID,"Sub");